# fetch records from 2 tables and check if submitted checkbox id value exist

Tags: php, pdo

i have this form which fetch checkbox results from

1. tags

now i wish to compare if the submitted post id and value exist in a table and throw error

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts_tags WHERE post_id = :post_id AND tag_id = :tag_id');
        $stmt->bindParam(':post_id', $postID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':tag_id', $postTag, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $r = $stmt->rowCount();

        if(!empty($r)){
            $error[] = 'Please do not select exsisting tag.';
}
```

and here is the bit of code from my form

```
<input type='hidden' name='postID' value='<?php echo $row['postID'];?>'>
<p><label>Tags</label><br />
        <div class="boxcheck">
        <?php                   
                    $stmt = $db->prepare('select * from blog_tags');
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $tag = $stmt->fetchAll();
                    foreach($tag as $tags){
                    ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="postTag[]" value="<?php echo $tags['tagID']; ?>"> <?php echo $tags['tagName']; ?><br /> 

                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
```

what could i be possibly doing from that the error does not shoots?

thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** `$postTag`  is array your Binding it as a int .

**2nd :** you need to use `IN` clause in query

**3rd :** You need to bind the values in this way .

```
$inClause=array();
$i=1;
foreach($postTag as $row){
  $inClause[]=':postTag'.$i;
  $i++;
}

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts_tags WHERE post_id = :post_id AND tag_id IN ('.explode(',',$inClause).')');
        $stmt->bindParam(':post_id', $postID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$i=1;
foreach($postTag as $row){
  $stmt->bindParam('postTag'.$i, $row, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $i++;
}
$res =    $stmt->execute();
$r = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: still no error shows up if post_id and tag_)id exist in the post_tags table exist $r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if(!empty($r)){
     $error[] = 'tag exist.';
  }

Comment: your forgot to execute the query `$stmt->execute();` @ChristineMay

Comment: get this Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

Comment: Glad it help you :) @ChristineMay

Comment: u r kind and helpful person :-*

Comment: can you help with this topic too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671548/what-is-it-that-i-am-doing-wrong-while-converting